# Running OleDb Error 80040E10: Parameter ?_2 has no default value

Tags: vb.net, oledb, oledbconnection

a, b, c are strings and is all within a using block. I get the error in the title: Parameter ?_2 has no default value. Does anyone know what this means? I've added default values to the variables addressed and still no change. Am I missing something?

```
dbc.open()
Dim trans As OleDbTransaction = dbc.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
Dim cmd As new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO " & a & " (x, y) VALUES (?, ?)", dbc, trans)
cmd.parameters.add(New OleDbParameter("x", b)
cmd.parameters.add(New OleDbParameter("y", c)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
trans.commit()
dbc.close()
```

UPDATE: I tried using the syntax mentioned:

```
cmd.parameters.AddWithValue("y", c)
```

and

```
cmd.parameters.AddWithValue("y", if(c, DBNull.Value))
```

and nothing has worked as of yet. The if(c, DBNull.Value) added just seems to set values to null. I know what I'm entering is not null.

**update:**

The ? order was not ordered as they appear. I had a WHERE statement in the query that I placed at the start thinking the OleDbParameter string actually refered to something reasonable like actually pointing to the object. Why do

OleDbParameter("x", b)

if x doesn't actually refer to b and the order is all that matters? Anyway, thank you all for giving excellent and quick responses.

Comment: Is the (string) value for c blank or null?

Comment: What are the b & c types? Try using `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(...)` instead.  You should put [brackets] around your table name in case `a` has a space in it.

Comment: The c value could be blank. I didn't use DBNull to delimit that as an option, I might try that.
I'll try AddWithValue(...) as well.